# What happens to forces when a charge travels at near c?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, forces, charge

Suppose 3 electrons are travelling at $c - 1$mm at 1 cm distance

[image]

The charges are at rest relative to one another in their frame, but what happens to fundamental forces Fe and Fg? What Fe does A get from B or C? and what about B

Comment: I can't believe this gets down voted. This is a fundamentally interesting question. Using relativity as they define right now (ie absolutely relative), the distance between these electrons is defined relatively to be ... weird. Distance is determined by how much light travel in certain amount of time. If we fix the frame of reference is the frame that sees those electron moving at close to c, then the distances between those electrons are close to infinite which means Fe and Fg between them are close to zero which effectively means they lose both mass and charge as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the charges are moving at (near) c relative to a given reference frame (there is no mention of a reference frame in the question, but there must be one, otherwise we wouldn't know there is any - inertial - movement whatsoever), but they are at rest to each other, then according to SR postulates we may as well assume that they are simply not moving at all. We are free to assume they are stationary, and that the chosen reference frame moves at (near) c relative to them.

In such case the forces remain unchanged, as long as we do not have any information concerning possible influence of this reference frame on the charges.

Comment: After carefully reading, I recognize that the force will not change, but remember that in current construction of relativity, they have length contraction for moving objects which the definitely change the distance in the force formula and thus the value of the force. They will not be the same in that case.

Comment: Length contraction is not detected in any way in the frame of ref. in which it occurs. In other words, you always measure it in the other frame that you see as moving wrt. to you. So for the charges nothing changes and the distance between them remains the same, whether we consider them stationary or moving. Remember, in SR movement is relative, which means we are always free to assume **any** of the two frames that are moving wrt. to each other as stationary. So by definition, if the charges maintain the same speed then they are stationary wrt. each other, which means forces remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to remember the first relativity postulate to answer this one; essentially [Galileo's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_ship) that there is no experiment that an inertial observer can do to detect their motion relative to other frames *without making use of information from outside that frame*.

Therefore, the forces that any of the charges feels do not change from what they would be in any inertial frame: simply that calculated by Coulomb's law. If the charges are free to move, then they would begin to accelerate towards / away from one another (depending on their sign) according to Newton's 2nd law applied to them in a frame at rest relative to their beginning positions.

You can transform this force / initial acceleration picture to "your" inertial frame by Lorentz transforming the electrostatic field (encoded as the rank 2 Faraday tensor) and also transforming the force correctly: the apparent 3-force changes between the two frames and indeed one must use 4-velocities, 4-forces and 4-accelerations to calculate the dynamics of the system from a frame moving relative to the charges. The charges themselves and their invariant masses are of course the same in both frames. If calculated properly in this way, we arrive at the physically observed situation that both observers calculate the same trajectories for the charges.

Comment: Ah, I see now: you're worried about the Lorentz Fitzgerald contraction changing the forces, right? That indeed does "happen", as seen from the observer the three charges are passing. But it's not the only change that such an observer sees. You need to transform all lengths and forces as described in my last paragraph. All these changes work together to ensure that the trajectories of the particles are the same, whichever frame they're calculated in. For instance, we see B nearer A than C, but there are also magnetic forces from the other observers frame.

Comment: @ally There is an invariance, but of a different kind. $c$ is an invariant scalar. $m_i$ and $q_i$, the invariant masses and charges, are all scalars and are the same for both observers (forget about "relativistic mass", which is a messy notion outdated for its messiness). Forces and velocities need to be expressed as 4-vectors, then they transform by a simple Lorentz transformation. So their components will change, but then so too do position vectors transform (the Lorentz Fitzgerald contraction is part of this, as is time dilation), as do the components of the electromagnetic field ....

Comment: ....  so that both observers calculate the same trajectories for the charges, of course expressed in different co-ordinates.

Comment: Could you please say briefly if in our frame A gets same acceleration as B?

Comment: @user104372: Remember relativity of simultaneity. Since the charges repel each other, they won't keep moving at the same speed. So if _in the lab_ we can say that the charges are moving with the same velocity at some particular point in time, in the frame that moves with that velocity the two charges will not stand still _simultaneously_, which ruins the symmetry between the two charges. (And in any case the field each of them feels will depend on what the other one was doing _in the past_, not where it is "now").

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, they can keep moving at the same speed. There are more forces than Fe and Fg. They said that experiments show there are more bosons such as those that carry weak and strong force. This means you can make particles move using those two other forces and ask yourself about Fe and Fg.

Comment: @InformedA: Sure, but I was reacting to user104370's question about _matching accelerations_ which seems to assume that the charges are free except for the Lorentz force.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for the response, even though intuitively I am on your side. I don't think the existence of more than two forces makes sense. You have gravity which accumulates more of it and electricity which attracts to direction that reduces the accumulation, They are fundamentally different and there is no other characteristic to add more force. There might be some better explanation, though I do not fully get weak and strong forces.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, for the sake of clarity, just assume a very short time which doesn't greatly affect their relative position; are anyway the the forces Fe,Fg affected exactly in the same way?

Comment: @user104372: "Very short time" doesn't beat relativity of simultaneity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I was referring to your remark that "they won't keep moving at the same speed", even so how do you decribe the forces they "feel", can you?